# MS Bot get current page url - Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have created a bot with MS Bot SDK. Then, I want to get the page URL where I'm hosting the bot. Does anyone who knows how to get the current page URL from node.js?

I can see someone is trying to use Activity for getting the URL, but I can't find the right property from Activity.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the URL of the page where your webchat is hosted? (thus not your bot back-end). How do you embed the webchat?

Comment: Yes Mick, I am trying to retrieve the URL of the page where my webchat is hosted. I am using the option 2 of this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0, in other words,  embed the web chat control in my website using the secret key. Thank you!!